# django grpc json response to html template

Tags: json, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

need some help. Spent all day trying different permutations to no avail.

I am making a grpc call and formatting the response to a json. My goal is to pass the data onto my html template so I can format it how I want. The only thing I can get to work is to print the json on the page which is not what I want.

```
return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

^ this prints json on page but I actually want to populate certain parts to a table.

I tried the following (not all at once obviously):

```
return HttpResponse(branch_list)
return HttpResponse(response, 'src/grpc.html', {'branch_list', branch_list})
return HttpResponse(response, 'src/grpc.html', {'branch_list',branch_list})
return render(request, 'src/grpc.html', {'branch_list': response})
return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(branch_list), 'src/grpc.html', content_type="application/json")
```

This is my definition I am using in my **views.py** which works with the return statement
I pasted above:

```
...
def grpc(client_stub, payload_project_id=payload_project_id, grpc_stub_method=grpc_stub_method, metadata_okta_token_and_env=metadata_okta_token_and_env):
    client_stub = BitcClient(server, port)

    request = pb2.ListBranchesRequest(context=payload_project_id)

    response = client_stub.get_grpc_stub(grpc_stub_method).ListBranches(request=request,
                                                                        metadata=metadata_okta_token_and_env)
    #print(response)
    json_obj = MessageToJson(response)
    result = json.loads(json_obj)
    for data in result['branches']:
        # print(data['branch'])
        branch_list.append(data['branch'])

    return <need help here>??????????
```

I would like to loop through branch_list in my html template and sprint the branch name and branch status in a table in **grpc.html** template:

```
{% if branch_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for branch in branch_list %}
        <li>{{ branch.branch }}: {{ branch.status }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No branches were found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

my **urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.grpc, name='grpc'),
    ]
```

help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the correct return line needs to be: `return render(request, 'src/grpc.html', result)`